# Why is my virtual port linking to the original port in apache?

Tags: php, windows, apache, server

I am trying to create two ports `80` and `81` to render different files in my compute. For this I made a virtual host. My `httpd-vhost.conf` is as following:

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "D:\Softwear\Apache\httpd-2.4.23-win64-VC14\Apache24\htdocs\2"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "D:\Softwear\Apache\httpd-2.4.23-win64-VC14\Apache24\htdocs"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

In my `httpd.conf` file I have added `Listen 81` below `Listen 80` line. The problem is both `localhost:80` and `localhost:81` refer to `localhost:80`'s location.

When I run `httpd.exe -S` I get no mention of `81` port:

```
D:\Softwear\Apache\httpd-2.4.23-win64-VC14\Apache24\bin>httpd.exe -S
VirtualHost configuration:
ServerRoot: "D:/Softwear/Apache/httpd-2.4.23-win64-VC14/Apache24"
Main DocumentRoot: "D:/Softwear/Apache/httpd-2.4.23-win64-VC14/Apache24/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "D:/Softwear/Apache/httpd-2.4.23-win64-VC14/Apache24/logs/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="D:/Softwear/Apache/httpd-2.4.23-win64-VC14/Apache24/logs/" mechanism=default
PidFile: "D:/Softwear/Apache/httpd-2.4.23-win64-VC14/Apache24/logs/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
```

Comment: You are not including correctly the file you think you are including. Make sure the correct "Include" directive points to load "httpd-vhost.conf". If virtualhosts were there you would see the description of these virtualhosts you pasted bellow the "VirtualHost configuration:" entry of "httpd -S".

Comment: @ezra-s ah, thanks it worked now. I had to uncomment the include line.